# Deleting multiple rows from TableView

Tags: javafx, multipleselection

```
@FXML
private void handleDeleteAction(ActionEvent event) {
    for (Transaction transaction : transactionsTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()) {
        RemoveTransactionsCommand removeTransactionsCommand = new RemoveTransactionsCommand(transaction, transactionsTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems(), data);
        commandRegistry.executeCommand(removeTransactionsCommand);
    }
}
```

Why it won't work in case where I select more than one row, I mean it delete one row (sometimes two, but can't find what decide about it)

Here is command implementation:

```
public class RemoveTransactionsCommand implements Command {

    private ObservableList<Transaction> selectedItems;
    private Transaction transactionToRemove;
    private Account account;

    public RemoveTransactionsCommand(Transaction transactionToRemove, ObservableList<Transaction> selectedItems, Account account) {
        this.account = account;
        this.transactionToRemove = transactionToRemove;
        this.selectedItems = selectedItems;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        int presentSize = selectedItems.size();
        return presentSize + "transaction/s removed";
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        account.removeTransaction(transactionToRemove);

    }

}
```

And removal command:

```
public void removeTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
    this.transactions.remove(transaction);
}
```

Additionally I wanted to know the size of actual delete operation but what I pass as a 2nd argument isn't static and for example when every row is deleted it will be 0.

Any advices how to improve it?
Full project can be found [here](https://github.com/Sukiennik/JavaFX-Projects/tree/master/pl/edu/agh/iisg/to/javafx/cw3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the selected items list may change when the list of items in the table changes. So the list gets modified while you are trying to iterate through it.

You should create a copy of the list of selected items and iterate through it instead:

```
@FXML
private void handleDeleteAction(ActionEvent event) {
    List<Transaction> selectedTransactions = new ArrayList<>(transactionTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
    for (Transaction transaction : selectedTransactions) {
        RemoveTransactionsCommand removeTransactionsCommand = new RemoveTransactionsCommand(transaction, selectedTransactions, data);
        commandRegistry.executeCommand(removeTransactionsCommand);
    }
}
```

(and change the type of `selectedItems` in `RemoveTransactionsCommand` to `List<Transaction>`).

Comment: It helped :). I changed it a bit and made the loop inside class which is responsible for adding/deleting, but everything is fine now. Thanks!